# Expression vs Predicate issues

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, lambda, expression-trees

I've got a bit of a challenge where I have to create an expression tree to represent a query input by the user. Since I don't have the time to create all the possible cases of user input, I figured that expression trees would aid me in solving this.

For the most part, it has. I am, however, a bit stumped. I am in the code below trying to perform a List.Find with a dynamically created expression. The expression, in short, is this:

```
list.Find(m => m.ListOfStrings.Exists(s => s == "cookie"));
```

where m is

```
class MyClass
{
    public List<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; }
}
```

I've gotten so far as to create

```
s => s == "cookie"
```

with expressions, no problem. I've also declared a methodinfo for Exists

```
var existsMethod = typeof(MyClass)
        .GetProperty("ListOfStrings")
        .PropertyType
        .GetMethod("Exists");
```

The only problem I have is creating an expression to invoke said method with the lambda as a parameter like so

```
var findLambda = Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.Call(
        Expression.Property(
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "m"),
            typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("ListOfStrings")),
        existsMethod,
        existsLambda),
    Expression.Parameter(
        typeof (MyClass),
        "m"));
```

It gives an understandable exception that

```
Expression of type 'System.Func`2[System.String,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Predicate`1[System.String]' of method 'Boolean Exists(System.Predicate`1[System.String])'
```

How the heck can I overcome this?

Full code:

```
private class MyClass
{
    public List<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; }
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    var myObject = new MyClass();
    myObject.ListOfStrings = new List<string>();
    myObject.ListOfStrings.Add("cookie");
    myObject.ListOfStrings.Add("biscuit");

    List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
    list.Add(myObject);

    var existsLambda = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s"),
            Expression.Constant("cookie")),
        Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s"));

    var existsMethod = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("ListOfStrings").PropertyType.GetMethod("Exists");

    var findLambda = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.Property(
                Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "m"),
                typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("ListOfStrings")),
            existsMethod,
            existsLambda),
        Expression.Parameter(
            typeof (MyClass),
            "m"));

    list.Find((Predicate<MyClass>)findLambda.Compile());
}
```

Comment: I know that 'dynamic' user input is a bit of a challenge in Linq, but if the user just specifies different values for a field to filter on, or different filters on the same element, you can just append Where clauses to the original filter and use the input in the filter itself. So in short: it's completely unclear why you're going through all this trouble and why you can't append Where clauses if necessary.

Comment: @Frans, because I can't simply let the user specify different values for a statically defined field. I need a fully dynamic solution to a) cut down on bulk-some code that needs to be maintained and c) offer extensibility with new classes in the class library beneath all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegates have different types:

```
public delegate bool Predicate<T>(T obj);
public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T arg);
```

The `Exists` method (and the `Find`) expect `Predicate<T>`. The Lambda expression compiles at runtime to `Func<T, TResult>`.

Try the following:

```
var existsLambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Predicate<string>), 
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s"),
                    Expression.Constant("cookie")),
                Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s"));
```

You can also use the generic [Lambda Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340145.aspx):

```
var existsLambda = Expression.Lambda<Predicate<string>>(Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s"),
                    Expression.Constant("cookie")),
                Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s"));
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew they were different types, I just thought it'd be smart enough to turn a Func<string, bool> into a Predicate<string>, since a predicate returns bool, after all... I'll try this when I get back to work - thanks!

Comment: I also know what it compiles to at runtime, the issue was that I couldn't send a Predicate<T> as a parameter, since Expression.Call expects an Expression - your code seems to solve that issue. Like I said, I'll give it a try at work tomorrow. Thanks again. =)

Comment: Awesome. Such a simple change. Thanks. =)

Comment: Do you mind terribly if I un-upvote your answer and delete this question? A lot of people seem to think it's not a good question. =)

Comment: @J.Steen, no problem ... It's your question :-)

Comment: Well, never mind. Can't delete a question with answers. I'll live with the occasional downvote. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the message, it tells you that Predicate is not compatible with Func.

Now, Predicate is defined as such:

```
public delegate bool Predicate<T>(
    T obj
)
```

and you have Func as such:

```
public delegate TResult Func<T, Result>(
    T arg1
)
```

Put together, you're trying to make these 2 delegates compatible:

```
public delegate bool MyClassPredicate ( MyClass obj )
public delegate bool StringFunc ( string arg1 )
```

Ie. string != MyClass.

I hope it made sense.

Comment: You're right, I totally managed to read that all wrong there, that said, try Bruno's suggestion.